# uploading a file from folder with out browse in asp.net

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, web-services

i just wanna upload  afile from a fixed path, so i dont want browse button, I need just a TextBox(Path of my file some thing like c:/junk/upload) and and upload button.some thing like
[TextBox.Path][UploadButton]

or can i get the code in java applets or any other lanaguage?

Comment: thats the reason i asked can we do using java applets or asp.net??

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, a webpage loaded in a browser from internet cannot directly refer the local file system. You need a desktop application or plugin to achieve this.

Comment: Thats the reason I ask in java applets or any other alternative, actually I'm a basic c# and c++ programer so any language that would be easy for me

Comment: I know that sir, thats the reason im asking how can i do in java applets, as i sadi im a c# and Cpp programmer

Comment: no we can make using asp.net or java applets and yes what you said is right, security reasons! , but every applications has a sand box limits and thats include file handling as default , and we achived that. with out problem

Answer (score 0):

no we can make using asp.net or java applets and yes what you said is right, security reasons! , but every applications has a sand box limits and thats include file handling as default , and we achived that. with out problem

Comment: Are you trying to reply to someone? Who is "you" referring to here?